# Adobe livecycle print button specific pages

Tags: forms, pdf, livecycle

I have created a 2 page pdf. Page 1 show instructions and page 2 is the form. I have spent days looking for a way and trying all sorts of different ways to complete this task and all of which doesn't seem to work for me. I want a print button that only prints page 2 (the form) and not page 1 (the instructions). Everyone in my organization opens PDFs with Nuance PDF Reader as adobe acrobat costs too much for our non profit organization and adobe reader does not allow forms to be saved. I understand Adobe Reader can fill out forms and print to PDF, however I need to save the form as quite often we only fill out half the form at one time and fill out the other half at a later date. I can be reached at oc@hnliteracy.com Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is that the form has been created with LiveCycle Designer (I assume that you have good reasons for using that piece of software).

Adobe Reader XI can save filled forms. However this is limited to PDF forms, but not XFA forms, created by LiveCycle Designer.

It is possible to add "Extended Rights" which allow saving filled forms with Acrobat Pro. However, there are usage limitations; you'd have to read the Acrobat EULA and decide whether it affects you or not.

In a PDF form, you can set a print command using (Acrobat) JavaScript:

```
this.print(false, 1, 1) ;
```

However, this kind of silent printing requires higher privileges (the meaning is explained in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website). Under some circumstances, the above command may prefill the print dialog.